# How to use while loop

Tags: java

Ask the user to guess a number until the guess is equal random number. press 0 to quit and ask the user if they want to play again.

My problem, 0 for quit is, not working. How can I make it work with while loop?
thanks

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Guessing
{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    String playAgain = "y";
    final int MAX =100;
    int randomNumber;
    int numberofGuess = 0;
    int guess  ;
    boolean flag=false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    Scanner inputYes= new Scanner(System.in);

    while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))//do
    { 
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and "+ MAX );
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(MAX) +1;
        numberofGuess = 0;

        System.out.println( "enter a guess(0 to quit):");
        guess= input.nextInt();
        numberofGuess++;

        if(guess >0)
        if (guess == randomNumber)
        {
            System.out.println("you guessed corect.");
            System.out.println("you guessed " +numberofGuess+ " times");
        }   
        else if(guess < randomNumber)
            System.out.println("you guess is too low.");
        else if(guess > randomNumber)
            System.out.println("you guess is too high.");
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (y/n)");
        playAgain = inputYes.nextLine();

    }//while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

}

}
```

Comment: You're missing curly braces around the first if and a break statement to end the loop.

Comment: please format your code when you ask a question

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs until the expression in parantheses is false:

```
while (true) {
  // this will be executed forever
}

while (false) {
  // this will never be executed
}

a = 0;
while (a == 0) {
  a = 1;
  // this will be executed exactly once, because a is not equal 0 on the second run
}

guess = 1
while (guess != 0) {
  // this will executed until the user enters "0"
  readln(guess);
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is pseudo code. It will not compile.